# Tabs directive not exposing an api in my scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

So I'm trying the Tabs directive and having some problems.

the structure is something like:

```
//routes
$routeProvider..when('/course/:id', {
    controller: 'CourseCtrl',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/course.html'
});

//course.html
<div ng-controller="CourseTabsCtrl">
   <tabset>
      <tab>
         <tab-heading>Title</tab-heading>
         <div ng-include="'/view.html'"></div>
      </tab>
      ....
   </tabset>
</div>
```

Problem is i can't access the api to enable or disable tabs, select a tab, in none of the controllers `CourseTabsCtrl` or `CourseCtrl`.

Is this because the directive is working on an isolated scope? and if so, is there a way to get around that? How can i fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js) and the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs), you should be able to pass in an expression to the `<tab>` directive, that dictates whether it is enabled or disabled.

```
app.controller('CourseTabsCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.expr = true;
});

<div ng-controller="CourseTabsCtrl">
 <tabset>
  <tab disabled="expr">
     <tab-heading>Title</tab-heading>
     <div ng-include="'/view.html'"></div>
  </tab>
  ....
 </tabset>
</div>
```

If however, this is not enough for you. You could *'hack'* the `tabset` directive and use another controller than the one currently specified. Now, you would have to replicate the old behaviour of the default `TabSetController`, but you could add functionality on top of it to cater to your needs.

The best way (I've found) to do this is to `decorate` the directive itself.

Like so:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('tabSetDirective', function ($delegate) {
    // $delegate in a directive decorator returns an array. The first index is the directive itself. 
    var dir = $delegate[0];

    dir.controller = 'CourseTabsController';

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

You could build further on this and *pass in* the controller to the directive itself.

```
<tabset ctrl="someCustomCtrl"></tabset>
```

The config block would then look like this:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('tabSetDirective', function ($delegate) {
    // $delegate in a directive decorator returns an array. The first index is the directive itself. 
    var dir = $delegate[0];

    dir.controller = function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
      return $controller($attrs.ctrl, {
        $scope: $scope
      });
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

**Note**: If you go with the decorator way, you may have to do it in the config block for the angular-ui module. In that case, you will probably want to have a look [here](http://www.hiddentao.com/archives/2013/11/04/an-improved-angular-module-split-your-modules-into-multiple-files/), to be able to configure third party modules without touching their core code.

A second gotcha to the passed-in controller way, is that you need to make use of `$injector` in order to get dependencies (apart from `$scope`, `$element` and `$attrs`) into the controller. This can either be done in the config block, or in the controller itself by adding `$injector` as a dependency, like so:

```
 app.controller('CourseTabsController', function ($scope, $injector) {
   var $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
   // etc... 
 });
```

**What the f* am I on about?**

Given that I don't personally work with the AngularUI Bootstrap components, and the fact that there is no plunker/jsBin available I'm throwing out some tips n tricks on how to add custom behaviour to third party components, without polluting their core code.

*To address the questions at the end of your post:*

> Is this because the directive is working on an isolated scope?

It very well might be, the idea of isolated scopes is to not pollute the outside world with their inner properties. As such, it's highly likely that the only live 'endpoint' connected to the `<tab>` directive API is the default AngularUI `TabSetController`.

> ... and if so, is there a way to get around that? How can i fix it?

You can either do what I've suggested and roll your own controller (bare in mind that you should **duplicate** the code from the `TabSetController` first), that way you should have full access to the endpoint of the `<tab>` directive. Or, work with the options that are available to the directive as of this writing and wait for some more functionality to be introduced.

I'll try to fire up a jsBin soon enough to further illustrate what I mean.

**Edit**: We can do the whole decorator dance and duplication of the old controller behaviour, without the need to pass in a new controller. This is how we would achieve that:

```
app.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('tabSetDirective', function ($delegate, $controller) {
    // $delegate in a directive decorator returns an array. The first index is the directive itself. 
    var dir = $delegate[0];

    var origController = dir.controller;

    dir.controller = function ($scope) {
      var ctrl = $controller(origController, { $scope: $scope }); 

      $scope.someNewCustomFunction = function () {
        console.log('I\'m a new function on the ' + origController);
      };

      $scope.someNewCustomFunction();

      return ctrl;
    };

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Here's a jsBin illustrating the last example: http://jsbin.com/hayulore/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I will definitely look onto it and try to fix my problem and I will accept this and reward you with the bounty as soon as i can.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of some use :) Let me know if you stumble upon any problems. I just tried this myself (grabbed ui-bootstrap off of the bower repository) and it worked just fine. The key is the duplicate the default controller behaviour. Sky's the limit after that.

Comment: See my latest edit for a more DRY approach to decorating the controller of the tabset directive. The downside is that you don't have the original implementation 'at hand', so you'll have to cross reference the source code if you want to hook into its implementation.